# How to Overlap Drupal Views rows

Tags: css, drupal, drupal-views

I have set a drupal View. Now, i want the each row to overlap a little bit of the row in top of it.

I've tried using position: relative; and then top: -30px; ( for instance ).
My problem lies with the problematics of relative positions. This would work for the second row. But because the "real position" of the row does not move, for the third row i would have to set top: -60px to compensate the second row. and so on with the rest, -90px. -120px.

I guess i could override the views row template, and add a different top value for each row. But i was wondering if there is a more general solution to this.

Comment: did you try negative margin? ie. margin-top -30px;

Answer (score 0):

you can try the following in your css:

```
.views-row { margin-bottom: -30px; }
```